# How can I get rid of these gasopods around my base?

Tags: subnautica

I built my first base in the Safe Shallows, where there are normally some gasopods roaming around. They are not aggressive, but when approached release these gas spores that do a ton of damage if you come into contact with the gas they release.

My issue is that, for some reason, three of these jerks decided that the entrance to my base is the place to be, so I get attacked by acid just about every time I exit my base.

I tried the stasis rifle and knife, but they don't seem to take damage. I read on the wiki that someone lured them away with Peepers, but I couldn't get that to work either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please don't roll back helpful edits.

Comment: I agreed with the rejection that said it didn't add anything to the post, and that I had the right to reject it. Similar edits I made on posts a while ago were also rejected and claimed to be attempts of garnering reputation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would personally try using either torpedoes from the Seamoth or PRAWN suit once you acquire them.  According to [the Wiki](http://subnautica.wikia.com/wiki/Gasopod), you can attach floaters to them to stun them like with a stasis rifle.  With the PRAWN suits drill upgrade, you can dish out some rapid damage to them while also protecting yourself against the poisonous clouds that their gas pods create.

I'm not sure how far you are into the game yet, but the PRAWN suit is likely the best way to go about getting rid of them.

Answer (score 6):

Timmy Jim's answer is probably the best way to do it normally. However, if you're okay with using the console, there's a slightly faster way. Use the `instagib` command to toggle "instagib" mode. While this mode is active, every living creature in the game (other than the Sea Emperor) is killed instantly after taking a single instance of damage. Be careful though - this includes you! Remember to toggle this mode off once you're killed the gasopods.

You might want to combine this command with `invisible`, which prevents other creatures from reacting to your presence. Just swim up to the target, knife them once, and you're done.

Comment: Rememeber, any use of console commands prevents Steam achievements,  Just in case that interests you.

Answer (score 0):

I preffer to use the Grav trap.

1. Identify the spots where you commonly swim close to this scum.
2. Put the active trap in the entrance of the cave, or in the middle of the way where you pass.
3. Be aware of the trap so you may have to clean it periodically from other fishes.

Repeat this for every spot where those gasopods bother you.

Comment: Is the gravtrap strong enough to pull these guys?

Answer (score -1):

Ram him with the Seamoth. He will be traumatized and just leave.